# Slick: how does one pass a SQL query string to a DAO?

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

Using Slick and the Play framework, I want to expose an interface that another service invokes. The interface accepts a query string and passes this string to a Slick DAO class to perform a query.

The Slick documentation mentions `sql"""SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME """.as[Material]` as a sample query, but I don't know how to pass this `sql"""SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME """.as[Material]` from outside the DAO class. Could someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Why you want use direct SQL query ? I suggest you to read about Repository-Services pattern(well explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648968.aspx) by microsoft)